# What is causing the ' invalid name error in Stata?

Tags: date, stata

I am trying to run the following code to reformat variables n(date1, date2) to dates from strings but am getting an error:

' invalid name
r(198);

I am using stata 15.0 (upgrade not possible)

This is the code:

```
    foreach var of varlist date1 date2 {
       gen double_d'var' = clock('var', "YMD hms")
       format d_'var' %tc
       drop 'var'
       rename d_'var' 'var'
    }
```

Would be grateful for some help.

Comment: Note that date-time variables should always be `generate`d as `double`. Using the text `double` as part of a name use fleetingly is nothing to do with that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the underscore after double and use `’ quotes (the grave accent and the standard single quote, or apostrophe):

```
clear
set obs 1
gen date1 = "2020/12/01 00:00:00"
gen date2 = "2021/12/01 00:00:00"
  
foreach var of varlist date1 date2 {
   gen double d_`var' = clock(`var', "YMD hms")
   format d_`var' %tc
   drop `var'
   rename d_`var' `var'
}
```

Comment: I was using the SO app and the grave accent did not render correctly. I edited the code to remedy that.